# Explain this factorization: $\sqrt{1+e^x} - \sqrt{e^x}=\sqrt{e^x}(\sqrt{e^{-x}+1}-1)$

Tags: factoring

I found this factorization in one of my math books: $\sqrt{1+e^x} - \sqrt{e^x}=\sqrt{e^x}(\sqrt{e^{-x}+1}-1)$
I don't understand how that is possible. Can someone explain what rules are used for this factorization? Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you bring $\sqrt{e^x}$ inside $\sqrt{e^{-x}+1}$ and multiply it out? In other words, what is $\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$ assuming $a$ and $b$ are positive?

Comment: @Moo I know what that is since the factorization answers your question. But I need to understand how that happens. $\sqrt {e^x}$ times -1 is obvious, but I don't understand the other multiplication.

Comment: $\sqrt{e^x} \times \sqrt{e^{-x}+1} = \sqrt{e^x(e^{-x}+1)} = \sqrt{e^x + 1}$

Comment: @Moo I understand it now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

$$\sqrt{1 + e^x} = \sqrt{\underbrace{(e^{-x} e^x}_{1}) (1 + e^x)} = \sqrt{e^x}\sqrt{e^{-x}+1}$$